# How to connect gopro hero 11 USB-C NCM to RJ45 LAN

Tags: usb-c, gopro

I am trying to use OpenGopro to control my Hero 11 camera and get live video feed. I can achieve this over wifi but I need to control it over a long distance and avoid the wifi connections which is a bit inconsistent.

According to the documentation: https://gopro.github.io/OpenGoPro/http_2_0#usb this can be achieved via USB CDC-NCM.

What I need is USB NCM to plug in my GoPro <-> adapter <-> Ethernet RJ45.

I feel like there should be a device out there to achieve this but I wasn't able to find any way to connect the USB NCM other than directly to my computer...

I doubt very much that a USB-C to ethernet adapter would work in this case but maybe I am wrong.

From what I understand, the NCM protocol is not directly compatible with regular LAN ethernet devices so a USB-C breakout pcb would not do the trick.

I have been looking for USB-C to LAN bridge but can't find anything that does this.

Any suggestions/comments would be appreciated.

FYI I am planning on using an ethernet to fiber adapter to have this work over 5KM...

Thanks, E.

Comment: You need to edit the question so it is not a product recommendation request or research project that does not allow for a more or less straight forward answer. This is meant as a tip to prevent the question from being closed.

Answer (score 0):

USB-NCM isn't "ethernet", rather it's a USB spec for devices that want to show as an ethernet device on the host system. The camera is always a USB device, but if it supports `USB-NCM` then it can show up as an ethernet device on a USB host (standard computer, raspberry pi, STM32 microcontroller, etc) so long as the host system has drivers supporting the `USB CDC-NCM` spec.

There are a couple of [USB standards for IP devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_USB). I have a generic USB 2.0 ethernet adapter (has gigabit ethernet via RJ45 on one side, USB Type-A on the other side) which shows up on Linux as a USB CDC-NCM device. When plugged in, an ethernet device named `eth1` is created.

When I plug in my android phone and enable "usb tethering", my phone shows up as an USB RNDIS device and an ethernet device named `usb0` is created.

I'm not aware of any products that connect to a USB CDC-NCM device and bridge it to an ethernet port. A Rasberry Pi B (or similar single board computer) might be the closest thing to a "turn key solution" you'll find. Basically when you plug in the camera, you'll see at least 2 ethernet ports (one is the camera, one is the built in ethernet, maybe more if your SBC supports Wifi or has a cell modem). [Create a bridge device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255489) to join the 2 ethernet ports together. A bridge device is like a virtual hub. Keep in mind that if you want the Pi to have an address so it can talk to the GoPro, the address should be configured on the `br0` device and the `eth0` and `usb0` devices should remain unconfigured.

I see the documentation you linked [explains the static IP the GoPro](https://gopro.github.io/OpenGoPro/http#section/Setup) assigns itself (in the 172.16.0.0/12 private address block), but it doesn't say what netmask the GoPro uses. If your computer uses an address of `172.16.0.1/12` it should still be able to talk to the GoPro even if its using a narrower mask.